# crash: libobjc.A.dylib`objc_object::release()

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics

there is a crash in my app, but it doesnt show me where the wrong code is, only some infomation in the picture, how can I find out it？
(er.. I can't upload image)

```
thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS 
(code=1, address=0x16dfd7000)
frame #0: 0x0000000184c397ec libobjc.A.dylib`objc_object::release() 
frame #1: 0x000000018609aa80 CoreFoundation -[__NSArrayI dealloc] + 84
frame #2: 0x0000000184c3a134 libobjc.A.dylib`(anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 836
frame #3: 0x0000000186096b28 CoreFoundation`_CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 28
frame #4: 0x0000000186166cec CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1580
frame #5: 0x0000000186096da4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
frame #6: 0x0000000187b00074 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 100
frame #7: 0x000000018c351058 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 208
frame #8: 0x000000010015c5b4 RedFinger`main(argc=1,argv=0x000000016fd03910) at main.m:16
frame #9: 0x00000001850a559c libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use exception breakpoint in debugging it will indicate you just before app crashes and you can get exactly the point where you get problem.

Comment: use another approach by using crashlytics in your app.